# how to guess and rename file from deleted rar has invalid encoding

Tags: character-encoding

i have many files and folders that extracted from many rar from jdownloader, and deleted after extract, some of it names are:

```
�������[�ς݂��ς݂� - �Ȃ��ꂭ������ (invalid encoding)
�R�e���} (invalid encoding)
??? - ? ??? ? 
���΂ɂ����� (invalid encoding)
```

i know that those name should be korean, chinese/taiwanese or japanese. and i know that we could convert those files using `convmv -f enc_from -t enc_to` but how to guess the current encoding of those files?

Comment: It is generally impossible to automatically guess the encoding of an 8-bit Asian filename since every octet is valid in most codepages. You've chosen the right tool 'convmv' and now you have some trial and error to go through.